# Can't Duplicate Vb.net User Form with VS 2019

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'm trying to make an exact copy of form1 for further editing. I found many tutorials all with exactly the same advice. Copy the 3 files form1.designer.vb, form1.vb, and form1.resx. Paste and rename with form2 to replace form1 in the filenames. Then with a text editor I replaced (carefully and with a count) all instances of form1 with form2. Then I opened VS and selected show all and the new form2 appeared in solution explorer but without the form in design mode. The vb code was there, just not the form. Also, in solution explorer the outline of the form2 was dotted, not the icon displayed in form1, indicating something screwed up.

Again, I've seen at least 4 or 5 tutorials and 1 YT video, all from 2019 or later, all giving exactly the same advice above. Using Visual Studio 2019.

Ability to duplicate a form rather than recreate from scratch. Don't care about the code, just the form itself in design mode.

Comment: No need to do that. Create a second Form. Go to Form1 and use the mouse to select all the controls on Form1. Press `ctrl-c` (on keyboard). Open the designer for the second Form. Press `ctrl-v` (on the keyboard).

Comment: Yes I know, you can even use ctrl-a to select all. But I'm curious why the solution above doesn't work and while not a big deal to start from scratch, copying using the clipboard will not resize the new form nor will it restore the background graphics I'm using on the form itself nor the images i'm using in picture frames. Also, it won't  provide the vb code. So once more, this is more  why this can't be done. If I can't get an answer I'll just redo it from zero.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for anyone stumbling on this post, I found the problem. The VB code for form1 had a bindingsource which was copied to form2. Removing the references to bindingsource fixed the issue. Found this by pure fluke I guess, but that was it.